# How to rake db:migrate on a Heroku staging pipeline?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I've setup an app on Heroku, and I've now also set up a pipeline for staging. I did this by creating a fork of my production app on Heroku, then adding this to the app pipeline under the "staging" stage.

Before this (when I only had the app in production), I pushed updates to heroku from the CLI with `git push heroku master`. I could then update the database for new features with `heroku run rake db:migrate`.

However, I'm not sure how you would do this with a staging app in a pipeline? I tried using the `--remote` appendage but it doesn't recognise the app (I think because the `--remote` was pre pipelines?)

I have auto updates from git setup so that my app-staging always mirrors my git master, and I've just added a new feature which includes a table. The view on the staging site is now returning an error as I haven't run `heroku run rake db:migrate` on the staging site.

I obviously don't want to push these changes to production without know this new feature works. So how do you do it? Any ideas how to rake db:migrate the pipeline staging database? I can't find any guidance in the heroku manual either :/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Run

```
git remote -v
```

to see your remote name.

Assuming your staging remote name is `staging`, then:

```
heroku run rake db:migrate --remote staging
```

[Read more](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/multiple-environments)

Comment: Ah I realise there was an issue my side. When I used `git remote -v` it was only showing heroku and master - there was no staging. I think the problem was I didn't create the staging with the CLI. So I had to unlink the staging site from git, then delete it. Then I created a new staging site with the CLI, linked that to the pipeline and GIT and then it works perfectly. Thanks!